# How to delete exactly one has_and_belongs_to_many association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

"Has and belongs to many" allows having multiple associations between same objects. So, I'm trying to implement shopping carts that may have several of some products in them.

```
# /app/models/cart.rb
class Cart < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :products
end
```

.

```
# /app/models/product.rb
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :carts
end
```

However, when I try deleting one many-to-many association, it deletes them all:

```
@cart = Cart.last
@product = Product.last
3.times { @cart.products << @product }
@cart.products.delete(@product)
puts @cart.products.count
# Returns 0; should be 2
```

Is there a way to delete only one association?

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: I am using sqlite3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem with your approach is that you are using the product itself directly without actually caring about the association involved.

**For example:**

When telling rails to delete the (Product 1) it means that it will search in the association table (`cart.cart_products.where(product_id: 1)`) and apply `delete_all` to the result.

**What you should do instead is:**

1. declare the relationship between the 2 object formally `has_many :cart_products`
2. then use it to delete a single instance `cart.cart_products.where(product_id: 1).first.delete`

NB: the name of the join table (`cart_products`) may be different for your application.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this.

```
cart = Cart.find(card_id)
product = cart.products.find(product_id)

cart.products.delete(product)
```

Comment: Tried that. It still deletes all associations.

Answer (score 0):

From [documentation](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#choosing-between-has-many-through-and-has-and-belongs-to-many):

> The simplest rule of thumb is that you should set up a has_many :through relationship if you need to work with the relationship model as an independent entity. If you don't need to do anything with the relationship model, it may be simpler to set up a has_and_belongs_to_many relationship (though you'll need to remember to create the joining table in the database).
>
> You should use has_many :through if you need validations, callbacks or extra attributes on the join model.

Which is what I am going to do in short while anyway. So I ended up using `has_many :through`.

```
# cart.rb
class Cart < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :carts_products, class_name: 'CartsProduct'
  has_many :products, through: :carts_products
end
```

.

```
# product.rb
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :carts_products, class_name: 'CartsProduct'
  has_many :carts, through: :carts_products
end
```

.

```
# carts_product.rb
class CartsProduct < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :product
  belongs_to :cart
end
```